# Facebook web intents. Do they exist?

Tags: facebook, api

I have worked on several APIs in the past. Specifically I have worked on Facebook Public API and Twitter web intents.

Now I am looking for an easy way to connect with Facebook for: liking, commenting and sharing.

Is there something like the Twitter Web Intents but for Facebook?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't have web intents. The easiest way to connect with Facebook for liking, commenting and sharing will be using many of the known [Core Concepts](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/coreconcepts/).